# Drools: get the 3 most recent Events

Tags: java, drools

I'm working on a small Drools project, because I want to learn more about using rule engines. I have a class called `Event` that has the following fields:

- `String tag;` A tag which can be any string.
- `long millis;` A timestamp. (Actually, this is converted from a JodaTime `LocalDate` field which is also in `Event`.)
- `int value;` A value that I want reason about.

I insert several hundreds of `Event` instances into my knowledge base, and now I want to get the 3 most recent events that are tagged with `"OK"`. I came up with the following code, which works:

```
rule "Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'"
when
    $e1 : Event( tag == "OK",
                 $millis1 : millis )
    $e2 : Event( tag == "OK",
                 millis < $millis1, $millis2 : millis )
    $e3 : Event( tag == "OK",
                 millis < $millis2, $millis3 : millis )

    not Event( tag == "OK",
               millis > $millis1 )
    not Event( tag == "OK",
               millis > $millis2 && millis < $millis1 )
    not Event( tag == "OK",
               millis > $millis3 && millis < $millis2 )
then
  # Do something with $e1.value, $e2.value and $e3.value
end
```

But I have a feeling there should be a better way to do this. This is quite verbose and not easily re-used: what if I want to get the five most recent events with `value > 10`, for example? I would end up copy-pasting a lot of code, and I don't want to do that :).
Also, the code doesn't look very 'beautiful' to me. I don't really like the repeated `not Event...` constraints, and I also don't like having to repeat the same tag condition over and over. (This example is a heavily simplified version of my real app, in which the condition is actually a lot more complex.)

How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the STREAM event processing mode and your events are ordered in the stream:

```
rule "3 most recent events"
when
    accumulate( $e : Event( tag == "OK" ) over window:length(3),
                $events : collectList( $e ) )
then
    // $events is a list that contains your 3 most recent 
    // events by insertion order
end
```

===== edit ====

Based on your comment bellow, here is how to achieve what you want in Drools 5.4+:

```
declare window LastEvents
    Event() over window:length(3)
end

rule "OK events among the last 3 events"
when
    accumulate( $e : Event( tag == "OK" ) from window LastEvents,
                $events : collectList( $e ) )
then
    // $events is a list that contains the OK events among the last 3 
    // events by insertion order
end
```

Just double check the syntax as I am doing this by heart, but it should be close to this.

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising. However, I can't get it to work; it simply does nothing, and the other rules in the drl file also stopped triggering. I have set the `EventProcessingOption.STREAM` and declared my Event class with `@role( event )` in the drl file. I'm probably missing something else; do you have any idea?

Comment: Assuming you are using Drools 5.4, you probably also need to define an expiration for your events with @expires( x ) where x is the time you want to keep events in memory.

Comment: I found out what was going wrong: from the 3 most recent events, it takes the ones with tag "OK", but what I need is the 3 most recent events with tag "OK", regardless of the items with other tags that may be interleaved with them. So I was getting no events, because there just weren't any "OK" events among the last 3. So, this still doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately... but it's close :).

Comment: Hadn't noticed you edited your answer; sorry! And I even started a bounty on this one... Getting closer, but still not quite what I am looking for: I'm not interested in "OK events among the last 3 events", but in "3 last OK events among all events"... I'll give you the bounty though, since there are no other answers and you've already put in so much effort on this :).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify 'not logic' like this

```
rule "Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'"
when
    $e1 : Event( tag == "OK")
    $e2 : Event( tag == "OK", millis < $e1.millis )
    $e3 : Event( tag == "OK", millis < $e2.millis )
    not Event( this != $e2, tag == "OK", $e3.millis < millis, millis < $e1.millis )
then
    System.out.printf("%s - %s - %s%n", $e1, $e2, $e3);
end
```

There was nothing said about cleaning events. Usually this is desirable, so you can achieve the same logic with deletion of the last event:

```
rule "Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'"
when
    $e1 : Event( tag == "OK")
    $e2 : Event( tag == "OK", millis < $e1.millis )
    $e3 : Event( tag == "OK", millis < $e2.millis )
then
    System.out.printf("%s - %s - %s%n", $e1, $e2, $e3);
    retract ($e3)
end
```

Let say each second you'll insert an event one 'OK' another empty '', here is the test:

```
@DroolsSession("classpath:/test3.drl")
public class PlaygroundTest {
    
    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();
    
    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
            drools.insertAndFire(new Event(i % 2 == 0 ? "OK" : "", i));
        }
    }
}
```

all three variants will produce the same triggering logic:

```
00:00:01 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=0]
00:00:01 --> fireAllRules
00:00:02 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=1]
00:00:02 --> fireAllRules
00:00:03 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=2]
00:00:03 --> fireAllRules
00:00:04 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=3]
00:00:04 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=4]
00:00:05 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [Event, Event, Event]
OK4 - OK2 - OK0
00:00:06 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=5]
00:00:06 --> fireAllRules
00:00:07 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=6]
00:00:07 --> fireAllRules
00:00:07 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [Event, Event, Event]
OK6 - OK4 - OK2
00:00:08 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=7]
00:00:08 --> fireAllRules
00:00:09 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=8]
00:00:09 --> fireAllRules
00:00:09 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [Event, Event, Event]
OK8 - OK6 - OK4
00:00:10 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=9]
00:00:10 --> fireAllRules
```

variant with `window:length(3)` will also deal with last 3 OK events. It is different on the beginning though: it will be triggered for 1 and 2 first OK events too. It will be also triggered once with empty list on the beginning if session doesn't contain any events. According to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR3/drools-docs/html/DroolsComplexEventProcessingChapter.html#d0e10678), sliding windows start to match immediately and defining a sliding window does not imply that the rule has to wait for the sliding window to be "full" in order to match. For instance, a rule that calculates the average of an event property on a window:length(10) will start calculating the average immediately, and it will start at 0 (zero) for no-events, and will update the average as events arrive one by one.

```
00:00:01 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, UnmodifiableRandomAccessList]
[]
00:00:01 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=0]
00:00:01 --> fireAllRules
00:00:01 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, UnmodifiableRandomAccessList]
[OK0]
00:00:02 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=1]
00:00:02 --> fireAllRules
00:00:03 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=2]
00:00:03 --> fireAllRules
00:00:03 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, UnmodifiableRandomAccessList]
[OK0, OK2]
00:00:04 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=3]
00:00:04 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=4]
00:00:05 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, UnmodifiableRandomAccessList]
[OK0, OK2, OK4]
00:00:06 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=5]
00:00:06 --> fireAllRules
00:00:07 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=6]
00:00:07 --> fireAllRules
00:00:07 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, UnmodifiableRandomAccessList]
[OK2, OK4, OK6]
00:00:08 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=7]
00:00:08 --> fireAllRules
00:00:09 --> inserted: Event[tag=OK,millis=8]
00:00:09 --> fireAllRules
00:00:09 <-- 'Three most recent events tagged with 'OK'' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, UnmodifiableRandomAccessList]
[OK4, OK6, OK8]
00:00:10 --> inserted: Event[tag=,millis=9]
00:00:10 --> fireAllRules
```