# Per which data object should I create my Drools/Kie session?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have the following POJO:

```
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String organisationId;

    private String resposibleName;

    private DateTime transactionTime;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    ...

}
```

that I would like to apply my rules to. For example, a sample rule might be on its amount:

```
rule "SampleRule"
    when
        $transaction : Transaction( amount > 10)
    then
        $transaction.setStatus(Status.INVALID);
end
```

and I also want to apply some more complex rules such as:

1. `WHEN` the sum of amount fields of Transactions per same `organisationId` within the last week (based on `transactionTime`) is greaten than `x`, `THEN` `$transaction.setStatus(Status.INVALID);`
2. `WHEN` there is a past transaction with same `responsibleName` as the current transaction being evaluated, but different `organisationId` than the current one, `THEN` `$transaction.setStatus(Status.INVALID);`

When there's a query being made to a RESTful endpoint:

1. I am creating a new `KieSession`
2. Adding a single `Transaction` object to the session,
3. Adding further transaction objects that might be related to the current one with a different POJO (e.g. say `PastTransaction` as the exact copy with the same fields with `Transaction`, I am adding multiple transactions made by the same `organisationId` with `PastTransaction` POJO so that I can accumulate amount field on those while being able to apply more elementary rules on my `Transaction` object.
4. In the same way, I am adding all transactions that are made by the same `responsibleName` with `ResponsibleNameTransaction` POJO, and write a rule to check if any of these is not equal to the one of my single `Transaction` object in the `KieSession`.

I was wondering if there might be an easier/more optimal way to achieve what I have been doing, and optimizing per which entity I am forming my `KieSession`s for. I have though of writing methods to my `Transaction` POJO and hit the db within the rule execution (e.g. write a method `getAllTransactionsByTheResponsibleName` which returns a list, then check if there's an object with different `organisationId`). In a same way I can add related transactions as a list to `KieSession` then query the list within the rule, which might at least save me from using the same POJO under different names.

**Update:**

Elaborating further based on comments, would that be feasible to keep about a billion `Transaction`s in working memory (a session for all transactions)? Or alternatively, I can put transactions per responsible/organisation into `KieSession` (session per responsible/organisation). Then how can I apply some rules solely on the fields of the latest transaction being evaluated (or even set a field on it) when there are multiple transactions in session (e.g. `$transaction.setStatus(Status.INVALID);` when #1 is true, `$transaction` being the one that is currently evaluated)?

Comment: If you have a Transaction are capable of selection other Transactions according to #1 and a second set according to #2, you won't need rules any more: you can compute the desired result from these two collections.  -- Typically, all Transactions are fed into working memory - possibly even in real time - and the rules find Transactions and sets according to #1 and #2 and evaluate everything dynamically. Of course, it depends how far back in time you need to go to detect a conflict according to #2. #1 is limited by a week, so you should know what to expect.

Comment: Do you mean methods on a Transaction that returns past transactions based on organisationId and responsibeName? What do you mean by I don't need rules anymore? I use Drools for many reasons, one of which is for non-tech people being able to edit the rules via workbench. Plus, I have 10m transactions per day, which might make it infeasable to keep all transactions in memory at all times.

Comment: If the fetching of related data sets (Transaction) from a DB depends on the rule (as your "more complex" rule suggests) you won't be able to let your non-tech people write this just via workbench. - Consider #1: whilw you fetch you might as well add and check; once beyonx you can stop. Consider #2: does it make sense to fetch all T's with equal responsibleName when you have the positive result when encountering the first one? -- Rules work well if the data is in WM, and it isn't necessary to use different class names for writing such rules.

Comment: @laune I see. Then the question becomes how can I set a field/apply some rules on the latest  transaction being evaluated when there are more than 1 in session. Updated my question. I appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible to let your non-techies romp completely unaided. A full discussion of what you may have to add would require full knowledge of all the rules, which I don't have. However, #1 and #2 from your Q can be handled even with billions of Transactions passing through your Working Memory.

Use case 1: Checking for a threshold per account in a time range can be done by keeping an auxiliary fact ("AccountSums") per account with n daily sums. With any new Transaction, either update the last sum, or "shift" sums adding 0 sums and set last sum, or create new AccountSums; maintain total of last n sums- The techies can write the check based on just AccountSums (or in combination with the (last) matching Transaction.

```
rule "check 7 days limit"
when
    $t: Transaction( $orgId: organisationId,
                     $transT: transactionTime,
                     amount > 0, status == Status.VALID )
    AccountSums( organisationId == $orgId,
                 lastTransactionTime == $transT,
                 runningWeeklySum > 1000000 )
then
    modify( $t ){ setStatus( Status.INVALId ) }
end

rule "create AccountSums"
when
    $t: Transaction( $orgId: organisationId,
                     amount > 0 )
    not AccountSums( organisationId == $orgId )
then
    insert( new AccountSums( $orgId ) );
end
```

You'll need at least one additional rule for "shifting" the sums, etc.

Use case 2: Maintain an auxiliary fact ("NameId"), with instances containing a responsible name and an organisationId (or a single instance containing a Map.) If another Transaction arrives, create a new NameId (or Map entry), or compare for equal and not equal Id.

History must be condensed if the volume of your data is as you indicate. It may be possible to let the boffins write simple evaluation rules, but devising rule patterns along the lines I've outlined here is, at least for condensing the meta-data, not something you can leave to the Muggles.

Comment: Thank you, could you please add a sample rule just to check the newly added transaction's amount for example? When a request made to some endpoint in my API, I will add it to the session, and would like to apply a very basic rule solely on it's fields, and set a field on it. Thanks!

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090295/drools-get-the-3-most-recent-events)?

Comment: I have sketched a couple of rules. No guarantee. This requires some circumspection w.r.t. time, when to elimit "stale" AccountSums and other details. But you should get the idea ...

Comment: Sorry my bad, should have been clearer. I have an endpoint where I make a request with a single transaction in the body, where I have to return the status of that particular transaction. The method you wrote sets the statuses of all transactions validating the rule, if I am not mistaken. I really need the status of that particular transaction which I need to return after applying the rules.

Comment: You are mistaken. At the end of fire all rules the (one) Transaction has been processed, set to INVALID or not. You then delete it from the session, and life goes on.

Comment: Oh, but then I need it in the session with some other Past transactions to determine the next Transaction's validity. Say I am using `from acumulate` to determine some sums, to determine the next transactions status, and for that I need all transactions in the wm. How is that possible?

Comment: I think I explained that? You don't have to sum again and again; you keep the sums for the last 7 days. When a new day starts, you discard the oldest.

Comment: Yes, but I have around 500 rules some of which rewuire individual past transactions. That's what I meant. E.g. If there's a past event with amount greater than x for that particular organisationId.

Comment: I can only outline use cases you describe precisely. No doubt, doing this for 500 rules would exceed what can be done in these comment dialogues. I'm fairly confident that many cases - if not all - can be dealt with by a digest of selected information (like my AccountSums and NameId). I cannot imagine a scenario where that would not be possible, but I may be too optimistic.

Comment: I see, thanks anyways. I also found [this](http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/Get-previous-fact-from-working-memory-td3399064.html), which I presume is your answer again?

Comment: I can only say: it depends. Also note that if validation is required for very many accounts, dividing the load should be considered.